# How to HttpUtility.UrlEncode for a binary image?

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio

I'm trying to pass binary image from `StudentSearch` page to `StudentIndividual` page. I would like to display that binary image through Image control in `StudentIndividual` page, all the other student details can be displayed successfully except for binary image.

This is my `StudentSearch.aspx` html code as below:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("~/StudentIndividual.aspx?SID={0}&FName={1}&LName={2}&HomeAddress={3}&Gender={4}&DOB={5}&Image={6}",
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("SID").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("FName").ToString()), 
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("LName").ToString()), HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("HomeAddress").ToString()), 
                HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Gender").ToString()),HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("DOB").ToString()),HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Image").ToString())) %>'
                Text="View Details" />
```

`StudentIndividual.aspx.cs` as below:

```
            LabelSID.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["SID"]);
            LabelFName.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["FName"]);
            LabelLName.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["LName"]);
            LabelHomeAddress.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["HomeAddress"]);
            LabelGender.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Gender"]);
            LabelDOB.Text = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["DOB"]);
            this.Image1.ImageUrl = "data:image/jpg;base64," + HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["Image"]);
```

The problem should be here, I've tried to remove ToString(), but it won't work.

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Eval("Image").ToString()`

Comment: First of all consider that the maximum length of Get request is about 8192 bytes and if your request exceeds this limitation, it will truncate your request, so the last querystring that contains binary text of your image will be truncated

Comment: @AminMozhgani How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Using Querystring for this purpose is not a good solution, change it completely. You can Use only SID in your hyperlink and you should retrieve image and other fields in pageload